# How to go through each element in Ordered List Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, html-lists

I am building a selenium script to automate a task for me and on the webpage there is an Ordered List with 25 elements like this.

```
<ol class="search-results__result-list">
<li class="search-results__result-item">
<li class="search-results__result-item">
```

My current code is:

```
ordered_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-results__result-list")
for x in ordered_list:
    ...
```

This code only does the first element then breaks.

Answer (score 0):

that's because there's only one element with class **search-results__result-list**

change it to look for following xpath to also include elements with class name **search-results__result-item**:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'search-results__result-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ordered_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='search-results__result-list']/li")
for x in ordered_list:
```

Would get all li tags in the ol element. You targeted a single class element.